# Using 3d Carousel project to create SPB Carousel style

Tags: android, 3d, carousel

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

Trying to change each item's angle to get something like the SBP 3D shell.

spb.com/android-software/shell/

Api level 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution

Modify Carousel.getChildStaticTransformation().
after `mCamera.translate()`, and before `mCamera.getMatrix()` add:

`mCamera.rotateY(-(CarouselImageView)child).getCurrentAngle())`;

Comment: Hello. I used this solution but it gives error in this line which you specify. Error : The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) CarouselImageView

Comment: try to use the '-' operator on the result of getCurrentAngle()